# Why is there a carriage return in the HTML 4 & XHTML !DOCTYPE declarations?

Tags: html, doctype

Why is there a carriage return in the HTML 4 & XHTML `DOCTYPE` declarations?

Eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

also, would there be a problem if I remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It allows it to fit in a standard 80 character wide display.

You need some whitespace there, so if you remove it, you have to put a normal space there instead (so it isn't going to save you a byte of data transfer). Doing so does reduce readability though.

Answer (score 3):

The carriage return is simply to break a long line up into multiple lines. It can be safely removed.

This is no different from inserting newlines between long HTML attributes to avoid having to scroll horizontally to read the whole line. The goal is legibility:

```
<a href="a really long URL with a big query string or something"
   title="Some longish title goes here"
   class="class1 class2 class3">Some text</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Code formatting.

Its just white space and safe to remove.

Answer (score 2):

It is there simply for legibility and to fit into 72 characters.  Can be removed safely.

Answer (score 2):

It's just to make the lines short enough so that the browser doesn't break the line in an inconvenient place. If it was written in a single line and the browser broke the line in a middle of the URL, for example between the dash and "transitional", and you copied it that way, it could be invalid.

When you use it in the code you can have it on a single line, or even break it up into more lines if you would like that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Or even:

```
<!DOCTYPE
html
PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
>
```

Comment: I'll guess that the string in quotes (`"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"`) is not allowed to be broken into lines?!?

Comment: @Guffa, In what situation and which browser could do that ?

Comment: @Uwe You are correct, whitespace within a string delimited by quotes is always important, across virtually all programming languages.

Comment: @Guffa I'm not sure what you mean, to make sure "the browser doesn't break the line in an inconvenient place". The browser will never insert line breaks into your markup, the newline in this case is entirely for legibility and has no effect whatsoever on how the markup is interpreted by the browser.

Comment: @Cybrix: All browsers do that. If you have a line that it wider than it's parent element, it automatically breaks. You can see 20-30 examples of that on this page, for example.

Comment: @meagar: I'm not talking about the markup, I am talking about how it's displayed on the page. It's likely that it's copied from here, where you see how it wouldn't fit on a single line (unless you have high resolution and a maximised browser): http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: @Guffa Ah. I don't really think that has anything to do with why there is a line break there, especially since copy-and-paste ignores the breaks generated by word-wrapping in the browser. I don't think the default assumption should be that people are referring to how a browser will display raw code when they talk about code formatting. If that were really the concern over at http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html, they would have added a `<pre>` tag or applied a `whitespace:pre` style.

Comment: @Guffa Thank you, @maegar if I understand him well, that means we shouldn't remove that line break in case the browsers break it by itself and break it in the wrong place and make it "unreadable".

Comment: @Cybrix Actually... no. You should use the line break to make it more readable for yourself; the browser doesn't care whether it is there or not. Keep it or remove it depending on your preference, but don't worry about the browser being affected in any way by it.